# OpenCV : Unhandled exception at 0x546F435C (msvcr120d.dll)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm beginner in OpenCV

i install OpenCV 3.0 And visual studio 2013 on windows 7 32 bit , i config them , i can run my webcam and that's works fine but when i use below code i get this error :

> Unhandled exception at 0x66C8435C (msvcr120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x555C3A43.

Code:

```
    #include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    /// Global Variables
    Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
    char* image_window = "Source Image";
    char* result_window = "Result window";

    int match_method;
    int max_Trackbar = 5;

    /// Function Headers
    void MatchingMethod(int, void*);

    /* @function main */
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        /// Load image and template
        img = imread(argv[1], 1);
        templ = imread(argv[2], 1);

        /// Create windows
        namedWindow(image_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        namedWindow(result_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        /// Create Trackbar
        char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
        createTrackbar(trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod);

        MatchingMethod(0, 0);

        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }

    /*
    * @function MatchingMethod
    * @brief Trackbar callback
    */
    void MatchingMethod(int, void*)
    {
        /// Source image to display
        Mat img_display;
        img.copyTo(img_display);

        /// Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

        result.create(result_cols, result_rows, CV_32FC1);

        /// Do the Matching and Normalize
        matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
        normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

        /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
        Point matchLoc;

        minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());

        /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
        if (match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
        {
            matchLoc = minLoc;
        }
        else
        {
            matchLoc = maxLoc;
        }

        /// Show me what you got
        rectangle(img_display, matchLoc, Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);
        rectangle(result, matchLoc, Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols, matchLoc.y + templ.rows), Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);

        imshow(image_window, img_display);
        imshow(result_window, result);

        return;
    }
```

and error line :

[Error Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVv6S.png)

And Error With Code :

[Error With Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/226eg.png)

just i want to test Template Matching , i tested with Visual Studio 2012,2010,2008 and Now 2013 , what should i do ? how can i solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot

Regards .

Comment: You're passing invalid input arguments wrong, so you can't load any image. Please post your input arguments under: Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command Arguments